# The type 'Pulse.Data.Entity.WHUserClaim' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUserClaim' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

hello I'm getting this eroor while creating dbcontextfile in mvc 
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0311  The type 'Pulse.Data.Entity.WHUserClaim' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUserClaim' in the generic type or method 'IdentityDbContext'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Pulse.Data.Entity.WHUserClaim' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim'. Pulse.Data  D:\projects\Pulse\Pulse.Data\AppDbContext.cs    16  Active
"

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<WHUser, WHRole, long, WHUserClaim, WHUserRole, WHUserLogin, WHRoleClaim, WHUserToken>
  {
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the name space which i was using in entity table for WHUserRole WHUserLogin WHUserClaim was incorrect after replacing using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework to using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity; it work properly :)